# if cell B1 is blank, find the next cell in column A with matching data that also has data in column B. Input the data found in column B into B1

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match

In column A I have multiple ID numbers, and most of them have duplicates.

In column B I have "Areas" associated with the ID number, but only one ID out of the duplicates has this associated "Area".

This leaves multiple blanks in column B that do not have "Areas" assigned. I need the blank cells in column B to find their matching IDs in column A that have an Area associated with it, and input this data into the blank cell.

My knowledge of Excel is limited, but where there's a will there's a way.

I tried to use CHAT GPT as a way of finding an answer with no result.

```
=IF(B1="", INDEX(B:B, MATCH(TRUE, (A:A=A2)\*(B:B\<\>""), 0)), B1)
```

Here is an example of the table that I am trying to create a formula for:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 222222 |  |
| 222222 |  |
| 222222 | Area 1 |
| 555555 |  |
| 555555 | Area 2 |
| 777777 |  |
| 777777 |  |
| 777777 | Area 3 |

Here is how I would like the formula to work:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 222222 | Area 1 |
| 222222 | Area 1 |
| 222222 | Area 1 |
| 555555 | Area 2 |
| 555555 | Area 2 |
| 777777 | Area 3 |
| 777777 | Area 3 |
| 777777 | Area 3 |

Any help I can get with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Try: `=XLOOKUP(A2:A9,A2:A9,B2:B9,,,-1)` or `=INDEX(B2:B9,MATCH(A2:A9,A2:A9,1))`

Comment: Thank you!!!! I've been wracking my brains for this perfect answer! Huge appreciation to you!

Comment: I have posted in answer how you would do when there is blank

Answer (score 1):

Try using `XLOOKUP()` and the use of `visible cells`

[image]

---

- Select the whole data using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to apply filters.
- From the filter dropdown select `Blanks`
- From `Home` Tab --> Goto `Editing` Group --> Click `Go To Special` or press function key `F5` click on `Goto Special`
- Select `Visible Cells Only`. (Short Cut is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>)
- Enter the following formula in the first cell and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> together.

---

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,A2:A8,B2:B8,,,-1)
```

---

- Remove filter to see all applied from below.

---

Or as alternative can use this formula as well, if you don't have `XLOOKUP()`

```
=INDEX(B2:B9,MATCH(A2,A2:A9,1))
```

---

Comment: `VLOOKUP()` should work as well